# See who is browsing the local net shared folder

Tags: shared-folders

I have a folder on my computer that is shared over local network. I have allowed guest accessibility.

My question is just out of curiosity (without any practical reason).
Can I see username or ip-address of anybody that is currently using this folder?

EDIT: I am using samba to achieve network share.

Comment: Is the folder shared using samba? If so, you can do a `sudo smbstatus` to see userids and IP addresses of people using the share.

Comment: That did it. Thanks.. Can I see some log file of past users?

Comment: You can try `grep "smbd" /var/log/auth.log` and see if that gives you some history.  Since you are indeed using samba, how about if I write this as an answer?

Comment: please update your question to reflect that you are using **samba**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the folder is shared using samba, you can do a `sudo smbstatus` to see userids and IP addresses of people using the share.

You might be able to get some history from `grep "smbd" /var/log/auth.log`

Comment: You could also add the log dir `/var/log/samba/`